# C struct with pointers initialization

Tags: c, pointers, struct

When a struct that contains an array of struct pointers is instantiated, 
am I guaranteed that all pointers in the struct array member will be set to `NULL`?

Here's an example struct:

```
typedef struct mmNode {
  int val;
  int board[2][NUM_PITS+1];
  int side;
  struct mmNode* children[NUM_PITS+1];
} mmNode;
```

IE: If I create an instance of the mmNode struct, will the elements of `mmNode.children` always be set to `NULL`?

Answer (score 17):

It depends how you initialise your struct.

```
mmNode a;                              // Everything default-initialized

void foo()
{
    static mmNode b;                   // Everything default-initialized

    mmNode  c;                         // Nothing initialized
    mmNode  d = { 0 };                 // Everything default-initialized
    mmNode *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));    // Nothing initialized
    mmNode *q = calloc(1, sizeof(*q)); // Everything zero-initialized
}
```

"Nothing initialized" means that all members will just have random junk values.  "Default-initialized" means that all members will be initialized to 0, which for pointer members will be equivalent to `NULL`.  "Zero-initialized" means that everything will be set, bitwise, to 0.  This will only work on platforms where `NULL` is represented with bitwise 0.

Comment: Will `calloc` correctly initialize `NULL` pointers ? I mean will `all-bits 0` always mean `NULL` ?

Comment: My GCC (4.6.1) gives me a warning "missing initialiser" when I write `= {0}`. Are you sure that's legit?

Comment: @cnicutar: No. "Zero-initialisation" isn't the same as "null-initialisation". The underlying representation of a pointer whose value was assigned the null pointer literal needn't be `0`. `[C99:6.3.2.3/3]`

Comment: @Kerrek: Hmm, strange.  C99 section 6.7.8/21 should allow this, I think.  But you're right, GCC doesn't like this with `-Wextra`.

Comment: @Oli: I think I'd agree with you re: `{ 0 }`

Comment: @cnicutar: Yes, you're right.  Hopefully the update to my answer addresses this.

Comment: @Kerrek: According to http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options, `-Wextra` enables `-Wmissing-field-initializers`, which warns about this, even though it acknowledges that they're implicitly initialized to zero.

Comment: Actually, I tried the following:

    mmNode* root = (mmNode*)malloc(sizeof(mmNode));
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<8;i++){
        if(root->children[i]!=NULL){
            printf("%d:%d",i,root->children[i]);
        }else {
            printf("NULL!:%d:%d\n",i,root->children[i]);
        }
    }
    
    
All nulls all the time! I am using gcc. Any explanations to that?

Comment: Oli, Tomalak and @Kerrek. thanks. 
Please look at the attached code. Can anyone explain why this is happening? 
Sorry for the messed-up code, don't know how to format that.

Comment: @Zahy: You can't format comments other than with backticks, but feel free to amend your original post! Also, being "indeterminate" includes the possibility of being zero - there's just no guarantee.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: `{ 0 }` is a valid initialiser - gcc chooses to warn because you *might* have made a mistake, but it's still valid C.

Comment: note: "Zero-initialized" and "Default-initialized" are terms that have been invented for this answer. They do not appear in the C standard.  The C++ standard does use those terms, but with very different meanings.